# Нажатие кнопок на сайте. Авторизация в ВК

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

Всем привет. У меня есть токен в вк,мне нужно, чтобы программа авторизировала пользователя в браузере(xNet) и заходила на сайт, нажимала на кнопку.
Возможно-ли это?

Comment: Да, возможно. Ваш вопрос сейчас не имеет смысла, уточните что вы пытаетесь сделать и что не получается.

Comment: @PsiHamster Добрый день. Сайт при входе сбрасывает вход, а вход там только через ВКонтакте. Я пытаюсь сделать вход в вк по данным(либо токену) и потом зайти на сайт и выполнить действие(нажатие на кнопку)